# C++, 2D vector segmenation fault

Tags: c++, vector

Hello I need my code reviewed because it segmentation faults on me.  It's because my 2D vector does not have memory allocated, but how would I do that?

```
std::vector <std::vector <std::string>> pdf_report::random_data (int num_entries, int report_type)
{
    std::vector <std::vector <std::string>> printer_control;
    int card_num_max = 999899, card_num_min = 100000;   // card number
    int vol_ent_max = 1000, vol_ent_min = 10;   // volume entered
    int vol_disp_max = 7, vol_disp_min = 0; // volume dispensed
    int cn_type_max = 10, cn_type_min = 1;  // card type
    int charge_amt_max = 400, charge_amt_min = 2;
    int vol_bal_max = 6000, vol_bal_min = 0;
    int auth_num_max = 9999, auth_num_min = 1000;
    srand (time (NULL));    // seed rand () with new values

    switch (report_type)
    {
        case 1: // Report 1: Card Number, Volume Entered, Volume Dispensed
        {
            // fill a string array with random values
            for (int k = 0; k < num_entries; k++) 
            {
                int randNum = 0;
                int randNum1 = 0;
                int randNum2 = 0;
                int randNum3 = 0;

                // fill column 0 for Card Number
                randNum = rand() % (card_num_max - card_num_min) + card_num_min;    // generate random numbers inside range
                printer_control [k][0] = int_to_str (randNum);  // set string array element equal to converted int

                // fill column 1 for Volume Entered
                randNum1 = rand() % (vol_ent_max - vol_ent_min) + vol_ent_min;  // generate random numbers inside range
                printer_control [k][1] = int_to_str (randNum1); // set string array element equal to converted int

                // fill column 2 for Volume Dispensed
                randNum2 = rand() % (vol_disp_max - vol_disp_min);  // generate random numbers inside range
                randNum3 = randNum1 - randNum2; // volume dispensed could be lower than the number entered, but not higher
                printer_control [k][2] = int_to_str (randNum3); // set string array element equal to converted int
            }   
            break;
        }
    }

    return printer_control;
}
```

I have more cases, but getting just one to work is all I need to copy to others.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: So, you know that your code seg-faults, because you haven't allocated memory and you don't know how to do this. Then why don't you ask how to allocate memory? :/ It would be also easier to read your question, if you provide variable name instead of "my 2D vector" slogan.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all I need is printer_control.resize (3); because I have 3 columns

Comment: What is the size that printer_control should have? num_entries x num_entries or num_entries x 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I assume that printer_control is a matrix of `num_entries x 3`.

To initialize your `vector<vector<string> >`, just do this:

```
printer_control.resize (num_entries);
for (int i=0; i<num_entries; i++)
   printer_control[i].resize (3);
```

Comment: It works now.  Thank you for your help.  So the first resize modifies in the y direction, and the 2nd resize modifies in the x direction?  2D vectors are less intuitive to use than 2D arrays

Comment: No, first resize the number of rows and the second, the number of columns.